# Does Andrew Yang support single-payer?

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election, healthcare, democratic-party

2020 Democratic Presidential candidate Andrew Yang’s website said [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190309005916/https://www.yang2020.com/policies/single-payer-healthcare/) on March 9:

> With **a shift to single-payer**, costs can also be controlled directly by setting prices provided for medical services.

Then on April 20, his website said [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420045244/https://www.yang2020.com/policies/medicare-for-all/):

> With **a shift to significantly more people receiving their care through a public option**, costs can also be controlled directly by setting prices provided for medical services.

And now his website just says [this](https://www.yang2020.com/policies/medicare-for-all/):

> With **a shift to a Medicare for All system**, costs can also be controlled directly by setting prices provided for medical services.

So my question is, does Andrew Yang support a single payer healthcare plan?  Or does he just support a public option?

If he has changed his view on this, has he addressed what caused the shift?

Comment: Is there a distinction between Medicare for All and Single-Payer? Both Warren and Sanders use the same term.

Comment: @Jontia Medicare for All is a vaguer term that some people use for things other than single-payer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems he's not taken a specific position yet.

[Bloomberg ran an article](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2019-opinion-democratic-presidential-medicare-debate/) entitled *The Democrats Are Fighting for Your Health in 2020* on 14 October 2019. In it they put Yang in the *Medicare for All-ish* box. Bloomberg describes this in-between option as follows:

> Think Medicare for All, but with some private insurance and out-of-pocket costs. This is a viable middle path that may offer many of the benefits of a single-payer system without quite as much disruption.

Specific to candidate Yang, the [Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2019-opinion-democratic-presidential-medicare-debate/) notes:

> Then, there’s what I would call the vague gang. Entrepreneur Andrew Yang and the other candidates listed above say they support Medicare for All as a goal. They just don’t necessarily agree with that whole getting-rid-of-private-insurance-in-one-fell-swoop thing. None of them have released plans that are detailed enough to give a sense of how much of the current system they’d retain.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Yang was not in favor of a single payer option nor of a public option. His plan centered around expanding Medicare to more people over time and trying to gradually outcompete private offerings, as per this [ABC News article](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/andrew-yang-pressed-health-care-plan-support-spirit/story?id=67959257).

Confusingly, his campaign used the term Medicare for All to refer not to the single-payer plans that were proposed under the name, but to the general idea of making healthcare accessible to more people. Here's how Yang described it himself in [an interview with MSNBC](https://youtu.be/sP_lPltuixQ?t=82):

> What Medicare for All means to many Americans is universal healthcare
> that's high-quality and low or zero cost, and that is exactly what I'm
> championing. We need to provide healthcare to all Americans, but I
> would not get rid of all private insurance plans immediately, because
> millions of Americans are on those plans, enjoy those plans, and in
> many cases negotiated for those plans in lieu of higher wages. The
> goal of the government has to be to demonstrate that we can outcompete
> the private insurance plans and squeeze them out of the market over
> time.